# VB6 split function runtime error 9 subscript out of range

Tags: vb6, network-programming

```
token = Split(thisfile, "List1")(1)

token = RC4(token, Passwd)
```

On first line i get on vb6 runtime error 9 subscript out of range
I haved tried with UBound but dont work...on windows 7 64 bits this error dont appear...only on 32 bits?

full code (file scope - encryption):

```
Const mypass = "Passwd"

Sub Main()

Dim thisfile As String, token As String, selfpath As String

'The path to itself

selfpath = App.Path & "\" & App.EXEName & ".exe"

'open itself and get all the data in one variable

Open selfpath For Binary As #1

thisfile = Space(LOF(1))

Get #1, , thisfile

Close #1

token = Split(thisfile, "List1")(1)

token = RC4(token, Passwd)
```

Comment: have a look at the size (and content) of `thisfile` and check wether the file you are reading really exists, and is the version you expect it to be

Answer (score 0):

Split returns a 0 based array.  You are trying to access the 2nd element (element 1).  Since you are getting this error, it means that "List1" is not found in thisFile.

Comment: I hex the file and List1 is on the right place...on 64 bits the same error are present only in vb6 debug mode but the program code run after is compiled

Comment: are you sure this can work? as http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb-string-array-functions-split-join-filter tells me, you can split on a single char ... I would have to power on my old pc this evening and check this.